# Microsoft OWIN Security oAuth Single Sign On ADFS

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs, owin

There are to things that I want to understand

1. Does Microsoft OWIN Security oAuth is completely built in on the oAuth 2.0 RFC.
2. I need a complete sample code that have client to Single Sing on ADFS using OWIN oAuth. What will the architecture for this Single Sing on

Many Thanks 
IK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) OWIN *is* based on RFCs 6749 and 6750 (oAuth 2.0 and Bearer Tokens), and whilst I can't say for certain that it's 100% compliant in every respect, that does certainly appear to be the goal, there's an interesting discussion on similar matters on the Katana forum [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/476912).

2) Have a look at [this](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WSFederation-DotNet), it's the Azure AD Git sample for WSFederation, recently mentioned in Vittorio Bertocci's Cloud Identity blog [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/29/use-the-owin-security-components-in-asp-net-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs/).